# AJAX not working within form and instantly sending me to PHP script? PHP/AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I've currently got a feature on my web application where you can add your skills by clicking the `"Add a Skill"` button, very simple and worked up until I tried to add something else into the mix. The error is the fact that when I click the "Add a Skill" button it acts as if that were the submit button and try's to execute the php script `skills/add`

I'm currently trying to make it so that my application constantly checks whether the text which the user is typing exists within the database which is represented with a green tick or red cross if it doesn't exist.

What I'm asking is can anyone see why this is not working as it should be?

VIEW

```
<form method="post" action="skills/add" id="container">  

<script>

$.fn.addSlide = function () {
return this.each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $num = $('.slide').length++,
        $name = $('<input type="text" class="inputField" id="autoskill-' + $num + '" name="skill-' + $num + '" placeholder="What\'s your skill?"></div><img id="tick" src="/images/tick.png" width="16" height="16"/><img id="cross" src="/images/cross.png" width="16" height="16"/>');
        $slide = $('<br><div class="slide" id="slider-' + $num + '"></div><br>'),
        $amt = $('<input name="amount-' + $num + '" id="amount-' + $num + '" class="inputField" readonly placeholder="Slide to select this skill level..."/><br>');
    $this.append($name).append($amt).append($slide);
    console.log($('#autoskill'));
    $slide.slider({
        value: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
        step: 1,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $amt.val(ui.value); 
        }
    });
});
}

$('body').on('click', '.addNew', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$('#newFields').addSlide();
}); 

var count = 0;  

$(document).ready(function(){   

$('.inputField').keyup(skill_check);

function skill_check(){
    var skill = $('.inputField').val();
    if(skill == "" || skill.length < 4){
    $('.inputField').css('border', '3px #CCC solid');
    $('#tick').hide();
}else{
    jQuery.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "skills/auto",
       data: 'name='+ skill,
       cache: false,
       success: function(response){
            if(response == 1){
                $('.inputField').css('border', '3px #C33 solid');   
                $('#tick').hide();
                $('#cross').fadeIn();
            }else{
                $('.inputField').css('border', '3px #090 solid');
                $('#cross').hide();
                $('#tick').fadeIn();
             }
        }
    });

}

$('.addNew').click( function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#length').html(count);       
    count++;
});

$('.submitButton').click( function(event){
    $('#container').append('<input type="hidden" name="count" value="' + count + '">');
});

});

</script>

<button class="addNew submitButton"> Add a Skill </button><br>

<div id="newFields"></div>

<input type="submit" class="submitButton" value="Save Skills">

</form>
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Do you see a JS error in the console when you either load the page or right after you click the button?  It seems to me that your event handler probably never fires.  To test, put an alert right inside the event handler for the click to see if you ever hit that line.  Also, it seems like you have two click handlers for the `.addNew` button.  Is that on purpose?

Comment: Steve, There is an error in the console for an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` on line 140 which is `});` just before the `</script>`. It is on purpose that I have 2 `.addNew`.

Comment: Bingo!  With a JS error on the page, your JS can't execute correctly... therefore you event handlers don't work... therefore your `preventDefault()` doesn't work... therefore the button behaves like a button.

Comment: @Steve How would I go about getting around this problem then?

Comment: You would have to fix the JS error... take a look at my answer below to see if that is the culprit.

Comment: It certainly was the problem, many thanks Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you pointed out in your comment above, you have a JS error on the page.  If you were to indent your code correctly, you would discover that it is probably due to a missing `}` to close the `else` after your `ajax` call:

```
<script>

$.fn.addSlide = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            $num = $('.slide').length++,
            $name = $('<input type="text" class="inputField" id="autoskill-' + $num + '" name="skill-' + $num + '" placeholder="What\'s your skill?"></div><img id="tick" src="/images/tick.png" width="16" height="16"/><img id="cross" src="/images/cross.png" width="16" height="16"/>');
            $slide = $('<br><div class="slide" id="slider-' + $num + '"></div><br>'),
            $amt = $('<input name="amount-' + $num + '" id="amount-' + $num + '" class="inputField" readonly placeholder="Slide to select this skill level..."/><br>');
        $this.append($name).append($amt).append($slide);
        console.log($('#autoskill'));
        $slide.slider({
            value: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: 5,
            step: 1,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $amt.val(ui.value); 
            }
        });
    });
}

$('body').on('click', '.addNew', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#newFields').addSlide();
}); 

var count = 0;  

$(document).ready(function(){   

    $('.inputField').keyup(skill_check);

    function skill_check(){
        var skill = $('.inputField').val();
        if(skill == "" || skill.length < 4){
            $('.inputField').css('border', '3px #CCC solid');
            $('#tick').hide();
        } else {
            jQuery.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "skills/auto",
               data: 'name='+ skill,
               cache: false,
               success: function(response){
                    if(response == 1){
                        $('.inputField').css('border', '3px #C33 solid');   
                        $('#tick').hide();
                        $('#cross').fadeIn();
                    }else{
                        $('.inputField').css('border', '3px #090 solid');
                        $('#cross').hide();
                        $('#tick').fadeIn();
                     }
                }
            });
        // MISSING } HERE
    }

    $('.addNew').click( function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#length').html(count);       
        count++;
    });

    $('.submitButton').click( function(event){
        $('#container').append('<input type="hidden" name="count" value="' + count + '">');
    });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use absolute path to your php script..

```
jQuery.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "full-path-to-your-script",
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending the form via AJAX you don't want this:

```
 <input type="submit" class="submitButton" value="Save Skills">
```

You want this:

```
 <input type="button" class="submitButton" value="Save Skills" onClick="SomeAJAXFunction()">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add return false to one of your functions.

```
 <input type="button" class="submitButton" value="Save Skills" onClick="return FunctionWithReturnFalse()">
```